# LaTeX 3 token list varables, mapping functions, differences between mapping inline and functions

Tags: latex3, token-lists

I am looking for a good explanation of the differences and use cases, between the `tl_map_function:nN` and `tl_map_inline:Nn`. I provide a MWE for the `inline` which also appears to be the fastest.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn\whatever:n{..{#1}~}
\tl_new:N  \tl_phd_temp_a
\tl_new:N  \tl_phd_temp_b
\tl_new:N  \tl_phd_temp_c
\DeclareDocumentCommand\Test{ }
    {
       \tl_set:Nn  \tl_phd_temp_a {Yiannis Mary John}
       \tl_set:Nn  \tl_phd_temp_b {{Lazarides}{Lou}{Smith}}
       \tl_concat:NNN \tl_phd_temp_c \tl_phd_temp_a \tl_phd_temp_b
       \tl_map_inline:Nn\tl_phd_temp_c{\whatever:n{##1}}
   }   
\ExplSyntaxOff 
\Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: I always thought the difference was expandability. With `\tl_map_inline:Nn` you have to define the function that everything is mapped onto. With `\tl_map_function:NN` you already have it defined, so it's expandable. And, the reason of `\tl_map_inline:Nn` is faster, I think, is that since it's not expandable, they don't care how to do the mapping, with `map_function` I guess they have to play a little more with the code so the map is expandable.

Comment: My comment applies to `seq_map`, sorry for the confusion. In case of `tl_map` it seems that `tl_map_inline` defines first the function and then maps, while the other one just maps.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks for the comments, just made me look at the code for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions `\tl_map_function:nN` and `\tl_map_function:NN` are fully expandable (with `x`-expansion, not `f`-expansion), while the `inline` version aren't.

The `function` version is also slightly faster.

### Example file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn\whatever:n{}
\tl_new:N  \tl_phd_temp_a
\tl_new:N  \tl_phd_temp_b
\tl_new:N  \tl_phd_temp_c
\tl_set:Nn  \tl_phd_temp_a {Yiannis Mary John}
\tl_set:Nn  \tl_phd_temp_b {{Lazarides}{Lou}{Smith}}
\tl_concat:NNN \tl_phd_temp_c \tl_phd_temp_a \tl_phd_temp_b

\cs_new:Npn \xinline
 {
  \tl_map_inline:Nn\tl_phd_temp_c{\whatever:n{##1}}
  \tl_map_inline:Nn\tl_phd_temp_c{\whatever:n{##1}}
  \tl_map_inline:Nn\tl_phd_temp_c{\whatever:n{##1}}
  \tl_map_inline:Nn\tl_phd_temp_c{\whatever:n{##1}}
  \tl_map_inline:Nn\tl_phd_temp_c{\whatever:n{##1}}
  \tl_map_inline:Nn\tl_phd_temp_c{\whatever:n{##1}}
  \tl_map_inline:Nn\tl_phd_temp_c{\whatever:n{##1}}
  \tl_map_inline:Nn\tl_phd_temp_c{\whatever:n{##1}}
  \tl_map_inline:Nn\tl_phd_temp_c{\whatever:n{##1}}
  \tl_map_inline:Nn\tl_phd_temp_c{\whatever:n{##1}}
 }
\cs_new:Npn \xfunction
 {
  \tl_map_function:NN\tl_phd_temp_c \whatever:n
  \tl_map_function:NN\tl_phd_temp_c \whatever:n
  \tl_map_function:NN\tl_phd_temp_c \whatever:n
  \tl_map_function:NN\tl_phd_temp_c \whatever:n
  \tl_map_function:NN\tl_phd_temp_c \whatever:n
  \tl_map_function:NN\tl_phd_temp_c \whatever:n
  \tl_map_function:NN\tl_phd_temp_c \whatever:n
  \tl_map_function:NN\tl_phd_temp_c \whatever:n
  \tl_map_function:NN\tl_phd_temp_c \whatever:n
  \tl_map_function:NN\tl_phd_temp_c \whatever:n
 }

\cs_new:Npn \y #1
 {
  #1 #1 #1 #1 #1 #1 #1 #1 #1 #1
 }
\cs_new:Npn \z #1
 {
  \y{#1}\y{#1}\y{#1}\y{#1}\y{#1}
  \y{#1}\y{#1}\y{#1}\y{#1}\y{#1}
 }
\cs_new:Npn \zz #1
 {
  \z{#1}\z{#1}\z{#1}\z{#1}\z{#1}
  \z{#1}\z{#1}\z{#1}\z{#1}\z{#1}
 }
\cs_new:Npn \zzz #1
 {
  \zz{#1}\zz{#1}\zz{#1}\zz{#1}\zz{#1}
  \zz{#1}\zz{#1}\zz{#1}\zz{#1}\zz{#1}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\zzz{\xinline}
%\zzz{\xfunction}

\stop
```

### `inline` version

This is the response by `time`

```
real    0m4.635s
user    0m4.613s
sys     0m0.016s
```

and this is the memory report

```
 140188 words of memory out of 5000000
```

### `function` version

This is the response by `time`

```
real    0m4.163s
user    0m4.139s
sys     0m0.020s
```

and this is the memory report

```
 140188 words of memory out of 5000000
```

---

What's to be preferred? I tend to consider `\tl_map_inline:nn` easier, because it doesn't require defining a new function, but when the code becomes complicated, the `function` version should be employed for better clarity. It should be adopted whenever the mapping to be performed uses a function defined elsewhere.

The `inline` version makes it easier to add break points; the `function` version needs a specially tailored function containing `\tl_map_break:`.

Also, the `function` version is a bit more complex when the mapping requires more than one argument (for instance we're in a nested mapping, using both the outer and the inner item).

Comment: Thanks for your fine answer. Personally I prefer the `function` style as it is nearer to the concept of callback in other languages.